# Iterate/increment webelements

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How can I iterate through or increment webelements as below:

example xpath:

```
.//*[@id='content']/div[5]/ul/li/ul/li[1]/a

.//*[@id='content']/div[5]/ul/li/ul/li[2]/a
```

Windows apps modules is the parent element.
AMExchange2007 and AMHealth are elements at the same level. I would like to iterate through the elements at the same level.

Above provided xpath's are of elements at the same level.
As requested adding HTML code:

```
<ul class="childpages-macro">
<li>
<a href="/display/DCM/Windows+Apps+Modules">Windows Apps Modules</a>
<ul class="childpages-macro">
<li>
<a href="/display/DCM/AM-Exchange2007">AM-Exchange2007</a>
<ul class="childpages-macro">
<li>
<a href="/display/DCM/Exchange2007+-+Hotfixes">Exchange2007 - Hotfixes</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/display/DCM/Exchange2007+-+Potential+Fixes+and+Diagnostic+Drops">Exchange2007 - Potential Fixes and Diagnostic Drops</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/display/DCM/Exchange-7.6">Exchange-7.6</a>
<ul class="childpages-macro">

<li>
<a href="/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=35359035">POC/Spike Sprint</a>
</li>
<li><li><li></ul></li><li></ul></li>
<li>
<a href="/display/DCM/AMHealth">AMHealth</a>
<ul class="childpages-macro">
<li>
<a href="/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37127678">AM Health 8.2.0.2 (Hotfix)</a>
<ul class="childpages-macro">
<li>
<a href="/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37129112">Sprint1 AC/AT's</a>
<ul class="childpages-macro">
<li><li><li><li></ul></li><li><li></ul></li>
<li>
<a href="/display/DCM/RCA+-+AMHealth">RCA - AMHealth</a>
</li></ul></li>
```

Sorry if the question is not very clear.

Comment: Can you share `HTML` code or page `URL` for the same?

Comment: Have edited the question with the HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood the issue, you might need to use below code:

```
counter = 1
while len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="childpages-macro"]/li/a[count(./ancestor::ul[@class="childpages-macro"])=%d]' % counter)) > 0:
    print("\n%d level links:" % counter)
    for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="childpages-macro"]/li/a[count(./ancestor::ul[@class="childpages-macro"])=%d]' % counter):
        print(link.text)
    counter += 1
```

The output is

```
1 level links:
Windows Apps Modules

2 level links:
AM-Exchange2007
AMHealth

3 level links:
Exchange2007 - Hotfixes
Exchange2007 - Potential Fixes and Diagnostic Drops
Exchange-7.6
AM Health 8.2.0.2 (Hotfix)
RCA - AMHealth

4 level links:
POC/Spike Sprint
Sprint1 AC/AT's
```

Comment: Can you explain : [count(./ancestor::ul[@class="childpages-macro"])=%d]' % counter
I am trying with similar structure but getting blank list.


((browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="page-children"]/a[count(./ancestor::div[@id="page-children"])=%d]' % counter)))



<div id="page-children" class="pageSectionBody children-loaded">
<span class="child-display">
<span class="icon icon-page" title="Page">Page:</span>
<a href="/display/DCM/AT%27s+for+AMhealthAM+9.2+SQLLite+discovery+support">AT's for AMhealthAM 9.2 SQLLite discovery support</a>
</span>

Comment: `/a[count(./ancestor::ul[@class="childpages-macro"])=%d]' % counter` means that we need `<a>` element with count of ancestor `ul` (parent, grandparent) elements that is equal to our current value of `counter` (links level). I can't advice correct solution considering just provided `HTML` sample. Can you share more details or submit new ticket

Comment: Thanks for that.. i could make the changes, was missing /span